# regex to qualify `n()`

Tags: pcre, negative-lookbehind

I'd like to replace `n()` with `dplyr::n()`.  I would like to match entries like

```
n()
 n()
a = n()
b = runif(n())
```

but **not** match entries like

```
function()
dplyr::n()
```

The [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/8XIhHG/2/) works, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

- pattern: `([^:\w]|\A)n\(\)`; substitution: `$1dplyr::n()`

Here are two unsuccessful approaches using [negative lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  The first (which looks for a non-**B**oundary, misses `dplyr::n()`, while the second misses `function()`.

- pattern: `(?<!\B)n\(\)`; substitution: `dplyr::n()`
- pattern: `(?<!:)n\(\)`; substitution: `dplyr::n()`

Note: I'm flexible on the regex flavor.  I'm most comfortable with using Atom to replace across multiple files in a repo.  (It's not really a constraint, but this code to by modified is R, which uses [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/).) The substitution pattern above is written for [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: The obvious approach would be `(?<![\w:])n\(\)`.

Comment: How does `([^:\W])?n\(\)` "work"? Your own link shows it matches everything, even the places it shouldn't match.

Comment: Thanks, @melpomene.  If you post that as answer, I'd like to accept it.

Comment: @melpomene, I got versions confused, but have corrected it now.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@melpomene's answer from the comments above:

```
(?<![\w:])n\(\)
```